# Does thickness or density of material between a wireless charging transmitter and receiver affect the power?

Tags: wireless-charging

I'm planning to build a small enclosure out of wood for a wireless charger and have been testing various thicknesses of wood to ensure my phone still detects and receives a charge, however, I'm only checking that the phone detects power transmission, not the rate of charge, which would require running lots of time consuming anecdotal tests.

Assuming conductivity properties of a separating material are equally non-conductive (i.e., no metal or wet wood), does the density or thickness of the material affect the rate of power delivery of a wireless charger?

For example: would 3mm thick walnut cause a reduction in power resulting in a slower charge than 1.5mm walnut?

Alternately, would 3mm thick walnut (680kg/m^3) cause a reduction in power resulting in a slower charge than 3mm thick butternut (370kg/m^3)

Comment: What operating frequency?

Comment: I'd expect materials which did not affect the resonant frequency of the inductors would have relatively minimal effect. In eg microwave ovens materials with substantial water content or conductivity will absorb RF energy - both being conditions that you aim to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you get a positive link between the transmitter and reciever, the practical charging rate doesn't vary that much.

Answer (score 0):

Coupling decreases as distance goes up, but most charging systems will compensate for this up to a certain point by increasing the drive level. Until that point is reached, there will be no decrease in power.

Once the limit is reached, power transfer will tend to decrease quite sharply (inverse cube of distance), and most system will cut off below a quite high minimum level.

To a first order this will mean max power transfer up to a certain distance, then a little further you will get nothing.